# Kohana 3.2. - Posting UTF-8 characters to external site

Tags: php, post, utf-8, kohana-3

I'm trying to post UTF-8 characters i.e. German accents to an external site. However when it gets there it appears like this:

```
Ã¶
```

instead of this:

```
ö
```

If I var_dump() with the appropriate UTF-8 headers I see the accented letter as it should be.

Here's the code I'm using when attempting to POST:

```
$request = Request::factory($url)
            ->method(Request::POST)
            ->post($params)
            ->headers('Content-Disposition', 'form-data; name="postdata"')
            ->headers('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8')
            ->headers('Content-Transfer-Encoding', '8bit');
$response = $request->execute();
```

Based on the guide here: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/requests#external-requests

The receiving URL is built on Java Spring. I have tested the posting process with the use of  JMeter. When posting UTF-8 accented characters it had no problem catching them. The headers in the PHP sample above use the same settings as the tests.

It has to be an issue with the PHP as the JMeter tests worked fine.

I am also able to pull accented UTF-8 characters from a database through to the website via the JAVA receiver site, then through PHP/Kohana/HTML and display them without problems.

**Further info:**

I have found that if I run

```
utf8_encode('ö');
// returns Ã¶
```

So I wonder if this is happening in the POST.

Comment: `Ã¶` looks like the binary representation of UTF-8 `ö` displayed with a latin-1 character set. Are you sure that this is not a display problem? At least the bytes went through, if you tell your browser to display that as UTF-8, you should see the `ö`. However if you encoded it *again* with `utf8_encode` than you won't.

Comment: It's not a display problem. I can see the accent fine if the input form fails at which point input boxes are populated with failed data. It seems to be something in the POST that causes it to change as by time the receiver gets it, it has the binary representation.

Comment: You have not added any code about the receiver, so actually you've only said that the sender side is working alright. However, the receiver side is unspecified in your question. So it's not actually possible to tell.

Comment: I'll add some info about the receiver.

Comment: Good idea, maybe it helps to spot the cause of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of playing around I have found the following code to work:

```
$data = http_build_query($params);
$request = Request::factory($url)
            ->method(Request::POST)
            ->body($data)
            ->headers('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');                       
$response = $request->execute();
```

The main differences here are that:

- Now use `->body($data)` instead of `->post($params)`
- `Content-Type` is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`
- `$data` variable is created by using `http_build_query()` on the original `$params` array